# How to get angularjs parameters in java backend?

Tags: java, angularjs

I have an angular app with these routes:

```
$routeProvider

    // Home screen
    .when('/', {
        title         : 'APP.NAME',
        bodyClassName : 'home',
        templateUrl   : 'app/custom/templates/customTemplate.html',
        controller    : 'customTemplateController',
        resolve       : { unauthorizeRequest: unauthorizeRequest }
    })

    .when('/connect/:connectionToken', {
        bodyClassName : 'client',
        templateUrl   : 'app/client/templates/client.html',
        controller    : 'clientController',
        resolve       : { updateToken: updateToken}
    })
   .otherwise({
        resolve       : { unauthorizeRequest: unauthorizeRequest }
    });
```

and on the java side:

```
@POST
public APIAuthenticationResult createToken(
        @FormParam("connectionToken") String token,
        @Context HttpServletRequest consumedRequest,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> parameters)

      HttpServletRequest request = new APIRequest(consumedRequest, parameters);

String token = request.getParameter("connectionToken");
```

The problem is that if I use a url like:

```
 http://localhost:8090/connect/{connectionToken here}
```

I always get null on the Java side.  And if I use a url like:

```
 http://localhost:8090/connect/?connectionToken={connectionToken here}
```

angular doesn't hit the correct route, it goes to the `otherwise` route, but on the Java side I can get the token via `request.getParameter`.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Not sure far down are you in your solution but can you use http headers to pass this kind of information (connection token)? Somehow it doesn't seem something that belongs to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your controller method like this:

```
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/connect/{connectionToken}")
   public Response doStuff(@PathParam("connectionToken") String token){
       System.out.println(token);
       //stuff..
   }
```

or, if you're using Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/connect/{connectionToken}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
public Response getOrderEquipment(@PathVariable("connectionToken") String token){
    System.out.println(token);
    //stuff..
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i just have access to the: HttpServletRequest on that method

Comment: i have edited my post so you can see the java method.

Comment: You're getting connectionToken from FormParam, but your token is a  PathParameter.
Try with : [AT]PathParam instead of [AT]FormParam